# When can I use "==" operator?

Tags: java, reference, equality, jls

I have found quote from jls:

> The equality operators may be used to compare two operands that are
>   convertible (§5.1.8) to numeric type, or two operands of type boolean
>   or Boolean, or **two operands that are each of either reference type or
>   the null type**. All other cases result in a compile-time error.

But this code

```
   String str= "";
   Number num = 1;
   System.out.println(str == num);
```

every operand is reference!

said that it is incompatible types.

Where did in jls say that these types should be compatible ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [section 15.21.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.3) (Reference Equality Operators == and !=):

> It is a compile-time error if it is impossible to convert the type of either operand to the type of the other by a casting conversion (§5.5). The run-time values of the two operands would necessarily be unequal.

Comment: Can you provide all situations when  I can use == operator without compile errors ?

Comment: @gstackoverflow: Just read all of section 15.21. But why do you need an exhaustive set of rules? I find it *very* rare to come up against this in an unexpected place. Unless you're trying to write a compiler, I wouldn't start trying to learn every rule.

Comment: I prepare to SCJP(new Oracle name uses now)

Comment: @gstackoverflow: Okay, well in that case just reading all of 15.21 is probably your best bet - and applying common sense. The compiler usually stops you from doing things which clearly don't make sense.

Comment: Yes. thanks) I just tryed to compare int [] and long [] through == and  I had fail(

Comment: `==` compares refereneces, not the contents of what they refer to. even if you had two different `int[]` with the same data it would still say `==` is false.  comparing `int[]` and `long[]` will always be false, unless they are both `null`

Comment: @Peter Lawrey - I am about compile fail, hence you are absolutely wrong

Comment: @gstackoverflow Interesting, I haven't tried it because even if it did compile it would still not do anything useful.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey This question was inspired by question from test. I am not compare arrays like this in real life